# Connect different point layers to one layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, compile

I have different projects, which all have a point layer. I would like to compile the data of these point layers into one layer automatically.

So that everytime when I add information to the point layer in project A and add information to the point layer in project B, it shall be compiled/added automatically to "Compiled point layer".

Sure, I could use the same shape-file or geopackage in every project, but if someone adds information to the layer in project A at the same time to someone adding information to the layer in project B, some data will not be saved correctly.
Does anyone know a good solution for this problem?

Comment: What you describe is a classical use case for a server-based database like e.g. PostGIS. It harmonizes perfectly with QGIS as QGIS was initially (some 20 years before) developped as a viewer for PostGIS databases. Like this, several people at different places can access, edit and change features without risking inconsistent data.